# Get specific parameter of url

Tags: php

The url is `http://www.test.co.uk/?set_cp_city=thecity` , normally i could use `$_GET['set_cp_city']` but that isn't working.  Perhaps something to do with the wordpress.  So how do i get the value for parameter `set_cp_city`

Here'ss my code

```
  <select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
<?php
$locations = array("London","Bristol","Manchester","Kent","Essex","Lancashire","Bedfordshire","Berkshire","Buckinghamshire","Cambridgeshire","Cheshire","Cornwall","County Durham","Cumbria","Derbyshire","Devon","Dorset","East Yorkshire","East Sussex","Gloucestershire","Hampshire","Herefordshire","Hertfordshire","Isle of Wight","Leicestershire","Lincolnshire","Merseyside","Norfolk","North Yorkshire","Northamptonshire","Northumberland","Nottinghamshire","Oxfordshire","Rutland","Shropshire","Somerset","South Yorkshire","Staffordshire","Suffolk","Surrey","Tyne and Wear","Warwickshire","West Midlands","West Sussex","West Yorkshire","Wiltshire","Worcestershire");
$current_city = $_GET['set_cp_city'];


echo "<option>$current_city</option>";

foreach($locations as $value) {
?>
<option value="http://www.test.co.uk/?set_cp_city=<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
<?php
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` and see if `[QSA]` exists inside of it. If it doesn't you may need to add it after one of the `ReWrite*` lines.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` should contain the query of the request, and you can use `parse_str()` with it

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: what is $output?;  i tried this and the result was `1`

Comment: try to echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and see if it contains your params

Comment: bro i think you need to set the value `$data = parse_url('url')`. that syntax is for `parse_str('query_string', $return_Value)`. but anyways, i don't know if this will still work, quite odd that `$_GET` aint workin

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```
$current_city = isset($_GET['set_cp_city'])?$_GET['set_cp_city']:"";
```